# How to configure pi for wifi at home using static IP and wifi at other location using dhcp?

Tags: wifi, dhcp, static-ip

I have a raspberry pi (jessie) which I would like to use both at home and at another location.

In case the raspberry pi is used at home then it should connect to my wifi router and use a specific static IP address.

In case the raspberry pi is used at the other location it should connect to that wifi router using dhcp.

How can I set this up so that it *automatically properly connects* to the wifi router when I plug the pi in at home (with static IP) or at the other location (using dhcp) ?

FYI I have already configured my pi properly for my home wifi router with static IP address.

My /etc/dhcpcd.conf :

```
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers
# Respect the network MTU.
# Some interface drivers reset when changing the MTU so disabled by default.
#option interface_mtu

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses instead of hardware based ones
slaac private

# A hook script is provided to lookup the hostname if not set by the DHCP
# server, but it should not be run by default.
nohook lookup-hostname

# JVA 2017-11-15 :  following lines added for static IP address
interface wlan0

static ip_address=192.168.1.133/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1

nohook wpa_supplicant
```

My /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=BE

network={
        ssid="bbox_jan"
        psk="xxxxxxx"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Comment: can your home router issue a static IP address using DHCP (even the cheapest routers can do that) - then you don't need to bother about it - just have the Pi get it's IP using DHCP

Comment: A very good comment but on my router (bbox3 provided by the telecom operator) I can not configure much.  I have only a user account and not an admin account for my router and the things I can do are very limited.  So I cannot set fixed IP addresses for certain mac addresses.

Comment: A Bash script that sets static IP, try to ping router, no answer = change to DHCP? That shouldn't be too hard to write.

Comment: I have again double checked my router and it is possible to configure static ip address for mac addresses.  (earlier I missed a bar that I could expand to get to those settings).  So I will implement the solution of @JaromandaX  Thanks .

Answer (score 5):

I'm answering a bit late I think but a solution exists, and I think it's worth mentioning it.

For each interface, it's possible in dhcpcd.conf to specify an SSID for which the configuration below will be valid. To do so:

- First stop dhcpcd (e.g run `sudo systemctl stop dhcpcd`)
- Open /etc/dhcpcd.conf
- Under your interface configuration write `ssid <name_of_network>`
- Write your static IP/router/etc. configurations for the aforementioned network.
- Repeat for each specific SSID you want to configure.
- Save your file, and run the command `sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl start dhcpcd`

Here is an extract of a `dhcpcd.conf` file of one of my Pi's. It should better illustrate this answer:

```bsh
[...]

# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0

interface wlan0
    # work's dev network static IP
    ssid work-dev-wifi
    static ip_address=192.168.0.186/24
    static routers=192.168.0.1

    # Gateway access point static IP
    ssid IoT-Gateway-Ap
    static ip address=10.0.0.4/24
    static routers=10.0.0.4

[...]
```

Normally it should do the trick !

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand the fixation Pi users have with static IP addresses.

In your question it seems particularly unusual; static IP addresses are assigned independently of any network - even if there is NO network present.

What you want to do is not possible - the OS has no way of knowing whether the static IP address is appropriate, and if assigned there will be no `DHCP` check, although you could possibly write a script to check.

It is possible to assign a static IP address if `DHCP` fails using a **Fallback profile**; See
[How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: @JaromandaX : I can cannot configure static IP addresses on my router.

Comment: 1/ My pi is also acting as a kind of "server" when used in the home network.  So the other devices in my home network expect the pi at a fixed IP address. That is the reason why I want to use a static IP address.   2/ I am fully aware that I should carefully assign the static IP address so that it won't clash with the dynamically assigned IP addresses by my router.  But if you know the range of IP addresses assigned by the router then it is pretty is easy to assign a static IP address that won't clash with it.

Comment: I have again double checked my router and it is possible to configure static ip address for mac addresses. (earlier I missed a bar that I could expand to get to those settings). So I will implement the solution of @JaromandaX Thanks

Comment: @JanVdA You can set a RESERVED address on your router - this is **NOT a static IP address** and requires DHCP. NOTE you can access the Pi at `hostname.local` - which is noted in the link.

Comment: indeed I can also access the pi by hostname.local instead of using the IP address.  Good point. something I will also plan to do in the future. many thanks for your advice.